# Are BLE devices required to respond to a SCAN_REQ requests?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, bluetooth-gatt

I have a BLE device that doesn't respond to SCAN_REQ and am working it out with the vendor independently per https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/issues/10660.

When I use Nordic nRD Connect iphone app as a client I can see that device in the scan list and can connect to it. However, when I use a different client, a python Windows one, that client doesn't show the device in its scan list and doesn't connect to it if I specify the exact address.

My question is, are BLE 4 devices required to respond to SCAN_REQ requests to be discoverable and connectable or is it just optional response to provide additional advertisement data?

EDIT, I believe that Emil's answer below (thanks) refers to this quote

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's required to reply with a scan response. That is defined in Bluetooth Core v5.3, Vol 6 Part B (Link Layer), section 4.4.2.3, using the word "shall".

There is one exception though. There is a Filter Accept List in the controller which can contain addresses of centrals allowed to scan and/or connect. There are four combinations the host can set (advertising filter policy) that control if this list shall be used for filtering incoming SCAN_REQ and CONNECT_IND packets, respectively. If you don't use this filtering mechanism, then the device must send a scan response to every scan request.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible approaches to scanning—Passive Scanning or Active Scanning.

Passive Scanning is when Scanners receive advertising packets and process the contents.

In the case of Active Scanning, however, a device may decide it wants to know more about an advertising device and respond to the initial advertising packet by sending a Scan Request GAP protocol data unit (PDU). This basically means ‘Tell me more.’ The device receiving the Scan Request ***can*** send back a Scan Response PDU with more information, once again in the form of a collection of AD types.

The above has been extracted from: https://www.bluetooth.com/blog/advertising-works-part-1/  [the emphasis mine].